# Read raster data with R which is in jp2 format

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I got the error `Error in .local(.Object, ...)`  while reading the sentinel2A data, which is in jp2 format, with R. I installed rgdal package (rgdal_1.2-8).

```
$platform---"x86_64-w64-mingw32"
$system---"x86_64, mingw32"
$version.string---"R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"
gdal version-----"GDAL 2.0.1, released 2015/09/15"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `raster <- readGDAL('you_file_name.jp2')`. You can read more about this here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211157/open-jpeg2000-sentinel-2-in-r

Comment: even after installing rgdal, GDAL I got the same error that - file format is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the jp2 file to tif (GeoTif) format

r code:

```
library(rgdal)
gdal_translate("image_band_name.jp2", "new_band_name.tif")
band1 <- readGDAL("new_band_name.tif")
```